# How do I request push notification permissions for android 13?

Tags: android

I've looked through this guide for android 13 push notifications

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/changes/notification-permission#user-choice

And I've looked at the guide for requesting permissions

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#java

I've updated my compile and target to api 32.

Here is my code so far (in progress).  Right now I'm just trying to get the notification prompt to show up.

```
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 32) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                return;
            ActivityResultLauncher<String> launcher = registerForActivityResult(
                    new ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission(), isGranted -> {

                    }
            );
            launcher.launch(Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS);
        }
```

The problem I have is I get an error `cannot find symbol variable POST_NOTIFICATIONS`.

What is the proper manifest permission for push notifications?

Comment: "I've updated my compile and target to api 32." -- are you *sure* that you updated `compileSdkVersion` to 32? That is when [`POST_NOTIFICATIONS` was added](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission?hl=en#POST_NOTIFICATIONS), so your behavior would be as if your `compileSdkVersion` was still something lower.

Comment: Oh, actually, it looks like `POST_NOTICATIONS` is added in 33.  I didn't realize 32 was android 12L.  That must be my problem

Comment: Oh, right, I keep forgetting that 12L was 32. I need to get that tattooed to the insides of my eyelids or something.

Comment: Did you solve your problem?  I am facing a similar issue.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky When I originally asked the question, api 33 wasn't released yet, so that was an issue for me.  But it is released now, so just change your target and compile sdk versions to 33

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky you're probably importing 'Manifest' from your package. Import from 'android.Manifest'

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Maybe I'm a bit late to the party, I know... But I hope this can help others at least. You need to use *compileSdkVersion 33* in your gradle file at the Module level. Then you'll be allowed to use the POST_NOTIFICATIONS permission without any issue.
[image: Gradle settings]

Comment: Doing this alone, won't still allow the user to receive push notifications, you need to request the permission as per @Manish Arora's answer

Answer (score 13):

You need to follow few steps, add post notifications permission in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>
```

then in your controller as for run time permission like generally we ask:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 33) {
   if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
       ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS},101);
       }
   else {
          createChannel();
        }
      }
```

Then Need to handle permission result as usual

Comment: I just upgraded from SDK 32 to 33. My notifications went missing. This was the best answer I could find!

Answer (score 5):

How to add run time permission for notification permission in android studio,
Apps targeting Android 13 will now need to request notification permission from the user before posting notifications,”
Behavior changes: Apps targeting Android 13 or higher
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/behavior-changes-13

Add on manifest: uses-permission android: name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS

and

Add in MainActivity after onCreate:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, POST_NOTIFICATIONS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{POST_NOTIFICATIONS}, 1);
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

> **Android 13 (API level 33) and higher supports a runtime permission for sending non-exempt (including Foreground Services (FGS)) notifications from an app: POST_NOTIFICATIONS. This change helps users focus on the notifications that are most important to them.**

**[reference here](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/notification-permission)**

So you need to add this permission to AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding android before Manifest as following:

```xml
android.Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS
```

It worked for me.

Comment: yes, it works for android V13 and above only.

Answer (score 1):

Declare in manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
```

add this code above onCreate

```
private ActivityResultLauncher<String> requestNotificationPermission =
            registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission(), isGranted -> {
                if (isGranted) {
                    // Permission is granted, perform your action here
                    showLocaleNotification("Dummy Notification");
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

then add this code where you show notification

if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
            String permission = Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS;
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), permission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                showLocaleNotification("Dummy Notification");
            } else if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(permission)) {

            } else {
                requestNotificationPermission.launch(permission);
            }
        } else {// handle below android 13 , just call showNotification()}
```

Note: this is just a sample, its better when your app is launched first time take the permission for notification and where you are calling showNotification function just check the sdk version and call showNotification function.

Comment: you registred notifications permission callback , but you dismiss to request permission when it is available : String permission = android.Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS;   ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity,new String[]{permission},req_code)