# PlayerNotificationManager not working on android 13

Tags: android, exoplayer

I'm new to android development, I'm building an application that supports playing video in the background. I decided to do it through Exo Player and PlayerNotificationManager. On Android 12 and below, everything works fine, but on Android 13, the notification does not want to be displayed at all, any ideas?

I use MVVM architecture, in my viewmodel's init method I initialize exoPlayer and playerNotificationManager

initialization code:

```
playerNotificationManager = PlayerNotificationManager.Builder(
    getApplication<Application>().applicationContext,
    1,
    EXO_PLAYER_CHANNEL_ID)
        .setSmallIconResourceId(R.drawable.racoon)
        .setMediaDescriptionAdapter(mediaDescriptionAdapter)
        .setFastForwardActionIconResourceId(R.drawable.ic_forward_10sec)
        .setRewindActionIconResourceId(R.drawable.ic_replay_10sec)
        .build()
```

After that, in my fragment, I assign exoPlayer to my playerNotificationManager in the onResume and onStop methods:

```
override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        Log.d("MyLog", "onResume")
        if (videoViewModel.playerNotificationManager != null){
            videoViewModel.playerNotificationManager?.setPlayer(null)
        }
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        Log.d("MyLog", "onStop")
        videoViewModel.playerNotificationManager?.setPlayer(videoViewModel.exoPlayer)
    }
```

Also I tried to register the following permissions in my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>
```

But the result remained the same, android 13 does not want to display my notification at all

Comment: Is notification permission allowed for your app?

Comment: It will ask once for the notification permission if your app doesn't targets android api level 33. System will handle notification permission automatically. But if notification access is not allowed then it will never ask for permission again and you have to enable it from the settings manually.

Comment: Thank you @primo , you helped me solve the problem. The problem was that my app's target sdk was 33, but I didn't handle notification resolution. I changed the target to 32, enabled notification on the device and it worked.

Comment: I am using a service for the same and setting the player to the playerNotificationManager in the service bind method. So What about that? How can we check inside the service that permission is granted or not and request about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on @primo comment and on this links:

- [How do I request push notification permissions for android 13?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72310162/how-do-i-request-push-notification-permissions-for-android-13)
- https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#request-permission
- https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/notification-permission#best-practices

I did the following to solve my problem:

In onCreate method of my fragment:

```
if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
        val launcher = registerForActivityResult(
            ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()
        ) { isGranted: Boolean? ->
            notificationGranted = isGranted == true
        }
        launcher.launch(Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS)
    }
```

In onStop method:

```
if(VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU && !notificationGranted){
        videoViewModel.exoPlayer.pause()
    }
    videoViewModel.playerNotificationManager?.setPlayer(videoViewModel.exoPlayer)
```

And then everything works fine.