# ReactNative and PermissionsAndroid 0.71 vs 0.70: POST_NOTIFICATION vs POST_NOTIFICATIONS and IllegalArgumentException

Tags: android, react-native, permissions

On https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.70/permissionsandroid it shows that this permission is available for verion 0.70:

```
POST_NOTIFICATION: 'android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATION'
```

On https://reactnative.dev/docs/permissionsandroid (version 0.71) it shows that the same persmission is then with an "S" at the end:

```
POST_NOTIFICATIONS: 'android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS'
```

Is this a typo?

In either case, if I use any of the above, the app crashes with

> IllegalArgumentException: permission is null
> at android.app.ContextImpl.checkSelfPermission(ContextImpl.java:2222)
> at android.content.ContextWrapper.checkSelfPermission(ContextWrapper.java:931)
> at com.facebook.react.modules.permissions.PermissionsModule.requestPermission(PermissionsModule.java:105)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)

when doing this:

```
async requestPermission() {
    try {
      const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.POST_NOTIFICATION, // or POST_NOTIFICATIONS
        {
          'title': 'TEST',
          'message': I18n.t('permissions.locationPermissionMessage')
        }
      )
      if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
        
      } else {
      }
    } catch (err) {
     
    }
  }
```

The permission is in the AndroidManifest file, confirmed.

**UPDATE**

Set compileSdkVersion = 33 and targetSdkVersion = 33 in build.gradle:

[image]

code for requestPermission not looks like (I am using 0.70.5):

[image]

and the crash is noted like so:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that requestPermission is called? and <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/> is added in your android manifest?

Comment: Hello, yes, I am sure. the AndroiddManifest.xml has, on line 8, the following: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>`. And yes, requestPermission is called, as it crashes on that one, saying that "permission is null" indicating that the `PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.POST_NOTIFICATION` is null, somehow...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on the [source code](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/fdd8002f1951007c85f1e5fe1b61fd16fe68f463/Libraries/PermissionsAndroid/PermissionsAndroid.js#L77), yes it's a typo that is fixed in `0.71.*` and also see [this pull request](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/35533) to know more details.

But about the crash, doesn't relate to typo in constants. First make sure to use **[compile sdk version 33](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73274205/7178860)**. And get this permission for androids equal or greater than 13(API_LEVEL 33)

In order to check ANDROID_API_LEVEL in js side use [DeviceInfo](https://github.com/react-native-device-info/react-native-device-info).

```js
async requestPermission() {
    try {
      const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.POST_NOTIFICATION, // or POST_NOTIFICATIONS
        {
          'title': 'TEST',
          'message': I18n.t('permissions.locationPermissionMessage')
        }
      )
      if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
        
      } else {
      }
    } catch (err) {
     
    }
}

// where you need to get permission
if (Platform.OS == 'android' && DeviceInfo.getApiLevelSync() >= 33) {
   await requestPermission();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the update and info. I tried doing just that; i set compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion to 33, added the if-statement and I am using POST_NOTIFICATION (without the S); I still get IllegalArgumentException, where it says that `permission is null`. Updated my question...

Comment: Are you sure that `requestPermission` is called? and `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>` is added in your android manifest?

Comment: Hello, yes, I am sure. the AndroiddManifest.xml has, on line 8, the following: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>`. And yes, requestPermission is called, as it crashes on that one, saying that "permission is null" indicating that the `PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.POST_NOTIFICATION` is null, somehow...